# ctrl+c to kill a bash script with child processes

Tags: linux, bash, bash-trap

I have a script whose internals boil down to:

```
trap "exit" SIGINT SIGTERM
while :
do
    mplayer sound.mp3
    sleep 3
done
```

(yes, it *is* a bit more meaningful than the above, but that's not relevant to the problem). Several instances of the script may be running at the same time.

Sometimes I want to ^C the script... but that does not succeed. As I understand, when ^C kills `mplayer`, it continues to `sleep`, and when ^C kills `sleep`, it continues to `mplayer`, and I never happen to catch it in between. As I understand, `trap` just never works.

How do I terminate the script?

Comment: Well-behaved applications that exit on SIGINT should kill itself with SIGINT  to let the caller respond too. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap#Special_Note_On_SIGINT . `sleep` should behave, hopefully `mplayer` does too.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the PID of `mplayer` and upon trapping send the kill signal to mplayer's PID.

```
function clean_up {

    # Perform program exit housekeeping
    KILL $MPLAYER_PID
    exit
}

trap clean_up SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
mplayer sound.mp3 &
MPLAYER_PID=$!
wait $MPLAYER_PID
```

Answer (score 1):

mplayer returns 1 when it is stopped with Ctrl-C so:

```
mplayer sound.mp3 || break
```

will do the work.

One issue of this method is that if mplayer exits 1 for another reason (i.e., sound file has a bad format), it will exit anyway, and it's maybe not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand what you mean. I thought the problem was that ctrl-c was trapped by mplayer, and did never terminate the fatherprocess..?

Comment: I read it again comprehensively and now i see that he is no able to terminate the fatherprocess.. so everything is fine

Comment: However, Oz123's answer is a more elegant solution

Comment: As I understand, in case of a read error it will also terminate with a non-zero code, and such termination is what the script is intended to handle. Unfortunately, I cannot find any docs on mplayer return codes and reasons.